# Rails: How can I update a page with new messages? via Ajax? Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to get some better logic behind this before I start writing code.

I have a model that collects new messages via a background process. (So the database gets updated every 2-3 mins with any *new* messages).

When the user comes to their inbox, they're presented with all their current messages. This is easy for me:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.messages
```

And I show the user's current messages on the page.

However, what if a *new* message comes in while the user is on that page (or any other page), how can I update the page w/ the new message without requiring a full page refresh.  I know this can be done via ajax (periodically_call_remote?) . But i'd like to  *only* highlight (fade/blink) only the NEW message that comes in.

Trying to wrap my ahead around this. My current solution is to use a partial for the inbox, which calls another partial of inbox messages. But how can I update the page with just "NEW" messages periodically? Say, to check every 2 mins or so.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your messages have a timestamp then you can use that as part of the ID for the new message (HTML IDs aren't supposed to start with a number). This will uniquely identify that message on the page and let you highlight it using JavaScript etc.

Comment: This is interesting John, I purposely put a timestamp on the records so that I could find all "new messages". (Messages with a timestamp greater than the last "update" call). However, How would I go about adding uniquely identifying them if each ID would be different? (Since each "new" message could have a different timestamp). Not sure if that makes sense...

Comment: and then there's refreshing the page... im thinking maybe periodically_call_remote would be sufficient for that.  Just thinking out loud here...

Comment: Ah ha!  just re-read my comment, didn't follow you at first but I think I get the idea. I'll add the timestamp to all id's of *new* messages and then highlight them that way.   We'll see if that works..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a periodic observer? (One that polls your app every X minutes)